# Creating Data Frame in C++ for predict() input in Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

Assume that we have a regression model which gets parameters named AA and BB as input. Assume that AA and BB are both double.

I know I should create a Data Frame in C++ and pass it as a parameter to the predict function.  I wonder how should I create and pass a Data Frame in C++? Why the following code does not worK?

```
            Rcpp::DataFrame dfin = Rcpp::DataFrame::create(Rcpp::Named("AA")=1.1,Rcpp::Named("BB")=1.2);
            std::string cmd2 = "predict(RegModel, todaydata = data.frame(dfin), \"probs\")";


            vector<double> prob_vector_reg_output = R.parseEval(cmd2);
```

Answer (score 3):

You may be confusing `Rcpp` -- which does indeed create the `data.frame` object for you -- with `RInside` which lets you evaluate expressions.

Look e.g. at `examples/standard/rinside_sample3.cpp` from the `RInside` examples: it shows you to access `lm()` results computed in R via RInside at the C++ side.  You could equally well pass data to the embedded R process -- but it still needs `RInside`.

On the other hand, R extension modules built via `Rcpp` can also access R functions, but that is done differently (and there are lots of examples around).

In either case, execution of the prediction step *by R* will always be at the speed of R, whether you control it from C++ or not.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I have a question in examples/standard/rinside_sample3.cpp. In this example we have "swisssum <- summary(lm(Fertility ~ . , data = swiss));" My question is how we can pass data generated in your C++ code to the lm() function. In this example it seems swiss is a pre-existing data.I thought we first should build a Data Frame filled with our data in C++ and then pass the Data Frame to the predict code.

Comment: Look at the dozen other examples which do that. As simple as `R["varR"] = varCpp;` where `varCpp` is a C++ object which will be assigned to the R object `varR`.